# Working with clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

I need to copy some text from my application to `Clipboard` in two ways. One is just a plain text, second is HTML format. I need to be able to paste the text to notepad and to Word document as well. Here is the code:

```
Clipboard.SetText(plainText);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(html);
```

The problem is I am able to paste it into a Word document, but not to a notepad.

**UPDATE:**
I tried this and I am able to paste to a notepad, but I am loosing my html.

```
Clipboard.SetText(plainText);
//Clipboard.SetDataObject(html);
```

When you copy formatted text(different fonts and colors) from Word document then you can paste it to notepad and to another word document without loosing the format. I need to be able to do the same.

Please help.

Comment: N.B. “loosing” = “to release or detach”. “losing” = “unable to find”.

Comment: @DourHighArch Sorry for my english. What I meant is I wanted to store information in both formats.

Answer (score 0):

You should use next format instead:

```
Clipboard.SetText(replacementHtmlText, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Read more [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbfb3z56.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: When you copy formatted text(different fonts and colors) from Word document I can paste it to notepad and to another word document without loosing the format. I need to be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.aspx) class to set both. Example:

```
var dataObject = new DataObject();
dataObject.SetText(yourRichText,TextDataFormat.Text);
dataObject.SetData(yourRichText,TextDataFormat.Rtf);

Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Comment: When you copy formatted text(different fonts and colors) from Word document I can paste it to notepad and to another word document without loosing the format. I need to be able to do the same.